# PrimeNg Datatable Custom Sorting repeating itself

Tags: angular, sorting, primeng

I have a datatable in Angular 2 app where I want to custom sort a column.

```
<p-column field="eligible" header="Eligible" sortable="custom" (sortFunction)="sortColumn($event)"></p-column>
```

In my component file, I'm making an API call to get the sorted results from the backend based on some logic.

```
sortColumn(colName: any) {
  let columnName = undefined !== colName.field ? colName.field : colName;
  let sortObject: any = {};
  if (this.sortedColumn === columnName) {
   if (!this.sortAsc) {
     this.sortAsc = true;
     sortObject[columnName] = 'DESC';
   } else {
    this.sortAsc = false;
    sortObject[columnName] = 'ASC';
 }
 } else {
  this.sortedColumn = columnName;
  this.sortAsc = false;
  sortObject[columnName] = 'ASC';
 }
this.getData(sortObject);
}
```

This API in return gets the whole data back and reorders the view. Now what's happening here is that this method **sortColumn()** keeps getting called repeatedly.

Can anyone please help me understand what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can to try event onSort of datatable

```
<p-dataTable [value]="data" (onSort)="sortColumn($event)>
  <p-column field="vin" header="Vin" ></p-column>

  <p-column field="eligible"  header="Eligible" [sortable]="true"></p-column>    

  <p-column field="year" header="Year"></p-column>
  <p-column field="color" header="Color" ></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

this event has event.field: Field name of the sorted column and and event.order (1 o -1) event.order. This event is invoked only when click in sort column.

I hope that it help you.

Comment: onSort($event) is not calling my method sortColumn() inside the component.

Comment: I had the same problem, setting the table to `lazy` solved it: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/5163

Comment: I do not get the sort icon using this code on my column

Answer (score 11):

I got repetitive http calling problem for using both onSort and sortFunction in p-table in Prime ng. Problem was solved using [lazy]="true",           (onLazyLoad)="customSort($event)" in p-table tag in angular8.

```
HTML:

<p-table [loading]="isLoading"
         [value]="listProjectClone"
         [scrollable]="true"
         sortMode="single"
         styleClass="custom-table borderless" [lazy]="true" 
         (onLazyLoad)="customSort($event)">
```

TS File Code:

```
import { LazyLoadEvent } from 'primeng/api';

customSort(event: LazyLoadEvent) {   
    this.sortBy = event.sortField;
    this.sortOrderBy = event.sortOrder == 1 ? 'ASC' : 'DESC';
    //http call to server
   }
```